# how to delete has_many association effectively ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

## scenario :

```
#app/model/user.rb
has_many :photos
```

Now, sometimes i have to do this

```
@user.photos.map(&:destroy)
```

This loads `N+1` query. Is there any way to make this scalable so it deletes in `1-2` query ?

I am using `Rails 4.0.0` and `postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.3.2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you define a [foreign key constraint with `ON DELETE CASCADE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK), all depending rows are deleted automatically when deleting the parent row. Then you only need a single command.

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = $user_id;
```

To just delete all photos and *keep* the user:

```
DELETE FROM photos WHERE user_id = $user_id;
```

Comment: thanks. But i dont want to delete the `user` record. `@user.photos.map(&:destroy)` means that `delete all photos row of user` but `not user` . This will be the case when **user wants to delete all this photos but not its entire profile**